# Four basic Java exercises - what should have been done better?

Tags: java

So I would be very grateful if you could check these four tasks - I'm a Java newbie and recently coded such things on a Introduction to CS test which I didn't score so well at and would love to know where my mistakes were, what I should do some other way and how can I get better at it to score higher again :)

> 1> Write a method that takes an array of integers (you can assume the
>   amount is divisble by four) and decodes them in the said manner:
>
> - add 15 to each integer unless it's equal to 0
> - divide the numbers in four-integer sub-words
> - let the first charater become the third, the fourth one be the first, the third - the second and the second be the last
>     
>   For example, {97,90,82,0} should output " api".

```
public static String decipher(int[] specArray)
{
    String finalWord = "";

    for(int i=0; i<specArray.length; ++i)
    {
        if(specArray[i]!=0) specArray[i]+=15;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<specArray.length; i+=4)
    {
        finalWord+=(char)specArray[i+3];
        finalWord+=(char)specArray[i+2];
        finalWord+=(char)specArray[i];
        finalWord+=(char)specArray[i+1];
    }

    return finalWord;
}
```

> 2> Write a method that takes a String as an argument and also returns
>   a String and processes it from left to right as follows:
>
> - if it finds a, it should add two a's to the result
> - if it finds two adjacent b's or one b alone, it should add one b to    the result
> - if it finds two c's, it should add them both to the result. If it    finds one c only, it should skip it.
>
> For example: "abaabbcbaccb" returns "aabaaaabbaaccb" and
>   "bbbbbbb" returns "bbbb".

```
public static String processWord(String inputWord)
{
    String outputWord = "";

    for(int i=0; i<inputWord.length(); ++i)
    {
        switch(inputWord.charAt(i)){
            case 'a':
                outputWord+="aa";
                break;

            case 'b':
                if(((i+1)<inputWord.length())&&(inputWord.charAt(i+1)=='b'))      // if there's at least one char left in the string and the next is b
                        {
                            i+=1;
                        }
                outputWord += 'b';
                break;

            case 'c':
                if(((i+1)<inputWord.length())&&(inputWord.charAt(i+1)=='c'))      // if there's at least one char left in the string and the next is c
                        {
                            outputWord += "cc";
                            i+=1;
                        }
                break;                

        }  
    }
    return outputWord;
}
```

> 3> Create a class MyClass with two class variables - myNumber of type
>   double and myString of type String. Also, add a default constructor
>   giving myNumber a value of 13.13 and myString value "some string" and
>   a constructor taking a double and String parameters, then assigning
>   them to myNumber and myString respectively. Add appropriate methods
>   for getting and setting the values of the class.

```
public class MyClass {
private double myNumber;
private String myString;

// CONSTRUCTORS
public MyClass(){
    myNumber = 13.13;
    myString = "some string";
        }

public MyClass(double d, String s){
    myNumber = d;
    myString = s;
        }

// METHODS
public double getNumber()
{
    return myNumber;
}

public void setNumber(double newN)
{
    myNumber = newN;
}

public String getString()
{
    return myString;
}

public void setString(String newS)
{
    myString = newS;
}
}
```

> 4> Create a method working similarly to String.indexOf() but taking as
>   parameters a source String in which it should look and String
>   containing the word it should look for in the source. It should return
>   an integer array containing all the occurrences of said sub-word in a
>   word denoted by indexes of the first letters.
>
> For example, ("ThiDFUs iDFs a DF D DFU sample.", "DFU") should return
>   an array containing 3 and 20.

```
public static int[] differentIndexOf(String source, String divisor)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> occurrenceFound = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int suspectedStart=-1;

    for(int i=0; i<source.length(); ++i)                                    // check the whole word letter-by-letter
    {
        if(source.charAt(i)==divisor.charAt(0))                            // if one of the letters corresponds the first one of the separator:
        {
            suspectedStart = i;
            for(int j=1; j<divisor.length(); ++j)                          // check the ones after it until the separator is fully used
            {
                if(source.charAt(i+j) != divisor.charAt(j)) suspectedStart = -1;  // (^) or until you find a difference
            }
        }

        if(suspectedStart != -1) {occurrenceFound.add(suspectedStart);}     // if no differences found in (^) => occurrence found
        suspectedStart = -1;
    }

    int[] finalArray = new int[occurrenceFound.size()];

    for(int i=0; i<finalArray.length; ++i)                             
    {
        finalArray[i] = occurrenceFound.get(i);
    }

    return finalArray;
}
```

Comment: It's best to just have one exercise per question, especially if they're unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmmm...

1> This looks mostly okay.  Probably the biggest help for you would be to extract adding the offset (15) to another method.  This should change your algorithm from O(2n) to O(n); that is, you only have to loop through the array once, instead of twice:

```
private static final int OFFSET = 15;

private static char offsetCharacter(final int character) {
    return (char) (character == 0 ? character : character + OFFSET);
}
```

Also, string concatenation is not really that efficient; you should probably use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), which will allow for the fastest writes (well, probably).  And a little error checking never hurt, even in cases where you are allowed 'assumptions.  Oh, and some of your names could use a little work.

```
private static final int WORD_LENGTH = 4;

public static String decipher(final int[] encodedCharacters) {

    if (encodedCharacters == null || encodedCharacters.length == 0 || encodedCharacters.length % WORD_LENGTH != 0) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Requires input array sized as multiple of " + WORD_LENGTH);
    }

    final StringBuilder decoded = new StringBuilder(encodedCharacters.length);

    for(final int i = 0; i < encodedCharacters.length; i += WORD_LENGTH) {

        decoded.append(offsetCharacter(encodedCharacters[i + 3]));
        decoded.append(offsetCharacter(encodedCharacters[i + 2]));
        decoded.append(offsetCharacter(encodedCharacters[i + 0]));
        decoded.append(offsetCharacter(encodedCharacters[i + 1]));

    }

    return decoded.toString();
}
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out a good way to deal with the swapping...

---

2> You're using String concatenation again, when you should be using a StringBuilder.  Things are a little convoluted here, probably due to the requirements for b/c (actually, I'm pretty sure that was the point).  Ideally, you'd be able to use [Regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).  Unfortunately, I'm not that great with it at the moment.
I'm assuming that all other characters are ignored (like you do).  Oh, even if there isn't anything to actually process, it's usually best to put a 'default' case in switch statements, as a deliberate declaration of expectation.  Somehow, it seems a little clumsy right now, but I haven't been able to come up with anything better...

---

3> Nothing much to go wrong with here.  You avoided the easy trap of making `myString` or `myNumber` non-private.  Some general stuff:

Usually, when you have constructors that set defaults, and one that requires all parameters, make the 'defaulting' ones use the other:

```
public MyClass() {
    this(13.13, "some string");
}

public MyClass(double d, String s) {
    myNumber = d;
    myString = s;
}
```

Also, getters/setters tend to have the *entire* name of the variable, instead of just part of it (so, `getMyNumber()`).  Note that this will depend on local coding styles to an extent; actually here, I'd probably prefer your choice, given the awkward names chosen by your professor.  Also, for setters, the name of the passed in parameter is often the same as the parameter it's setting, and the `this` reference is used to differentiate them:

```
public void setNumber(double myNumber) {
    this.myNumber = myNumber;
}
```

Oh, and the requirements didn't list them, but it's a good idea to put Javadoc on every exposed member (class, variable, and method).  Getters and Setters are usually pretty boring, though.

---

4> The requirements are a little sparse on this one.  I mean, it doesn't restrict me from using something like the [Apache Commons Utils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/index.html).  Heck, it doesn't say you aren't allowed to use `String.indexOf()` *inside* your method - although that obviously isn't the intent of the problem.  I'm going to assume that you're limited to the 'standard' JDK libraries.  And that you aren't allowed to use Regex here.
Oh, never use end-of-line comments.

```
ArrayList<Integer> occurrenceFound = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Whenever possible, use the *least specific* (most generic) object possible:

```
List<Integer> occurrenceFound = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Oh, you don't actually need to check *every* character in the string:

```
for(int i = 0; i < source.length(); ++i) {
    ....
}
```

After all, if you find the starting character as the *last* character, it's going to be a given it's not going to match, right?  What's the *actual* last character you need to check?

```
int[] finalArray = new int[occurrenceFound.size()];
```

Learn your libraries - the interface [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29) defines a couple of methods that would probably be helpful.

Breaking things up a little (and just using arrays) makes it a bit cleaner.  I'd really prefer some sort of 'Collections' based approach (ie something that [List.subList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) would work with), but that's probably too 'heavy'.

```
public static int[] differentIndexOf(String source, String divisor) {

    final char[] characters = source.toCharArray();
    final char[] search = divisor.toCharArray();

    final int[] occurrences = new int[characters.length - search.length + 1];
    int occurrenceCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length - search.length; i++) {
        if (stringMatches(characters, i, search)) {
            occurrences[occurrenceCount] = i;
            occurrenceCount++;
        }
    }

    return Arrays.copyOf(occurrences, occurrenceCount);
}

private static boolean stringMatches(char[] characters, int index, char[] search) {
    for (int i = 0; i + index < characters.length && i < search.length; i++) {
        if (characters[i + index] != search[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your big-O claim is confused. Technically, `O(n) = O(2n)`, there is no difference between the two classes. In terms of efficiency there is no reason to believe that combining the two loops will help at all.

Comment: @WinstonEwert - You're right, when compared to other progressions, there is no difference.  And the array access are likely to be fast regardless.  Still, it's usually best to attempt to reduce multiple iterations to one.

Comment: Why is it best to attempt to reduce the multiple iterations?

Comment: @WinstonEwert - Assuming that array access has a non-zero cost (and all operations will still otherwise be performed), the 'cost' of the function has been reduced by the length of the input.  2bn array access rather than 4bn sounds better to me.  While not as applicable to this situation, there are some languages that provide built-in mechanisms for operating on an array in parallel - however, they really only work for a single iteration.  With chained function steps (and preferably more than here), programs can really fly over data processing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation of my mistakes! :) The only thing I have a question about: in 4>, shouldn't _final int[] occurrences = new int[characters.length - search.length];_ be _final int[] occurrences = new int[characters.length/search.length+1];_? In the first case, it would create a 0-element array in case the search word is of even length to the source while it still can contain one instance.

Comment: Ack!  You're right about the `+ 1` bit.  However, given current requirements, you can't use `characters.length / search.length` - if you have a string of repeating characters, and a search string of the same characters (but shorter), there will be a 'starting' occurrence for every character (until `search.length` before the end).  I'd wanted to use the divided version too, originally.

Comment: You're right, it would crash on ("bbbbb", "bb"), for example. Also, we'd have to add an additional if in case of search.length being 0 (empty string as the search word). Thanks a lot once again :)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't test stuff well enough.  This is why, whenever you do any sort of coding, get a whole bunch of expected inputs/outputs you can run through it.  Any decent set of test inputs for 4 would have revealed the deficiencies right off.

Comment: I do not agree when you say "it's a good idea to put Javadoc on every exposed member (class, variable, and method)". This just bloats the code. I really believe that if you choose proper names for variables and methods, no comments are needed. Of course, if we're writing an API or so, Javadoc is a must. For the rest +1.

Answer (score 2):

In (3), its bad practice to update the counter of the for loop inside the body of the for loop.

It's better to use a while() loop here, since each iteration of the loop may consume multiple tokens from the input string.

For (4), this may be not be in the spririt of the question, but there already is an indexOf(substring, startIndex) method in Java which would be much more appropriate here.  Not sure if you are restricted from using that though.

Comment: Thank you a lot :) Yep, I was restricted from using indexOf, forgot to mention it as it was only verbally stated, not mentioned in the specs ;)

Also, why is additional incrementing of the counter inside for loop bad whilst being acceptable for while loop?

Comment: Its mostly about clarity.   If we see for (int i=0; i < 100; i++), most developers automatically assume it will get executed 100 times.  If we see a while or a do loop, we expect the number of iterations to be variable.